# How to get the contract address for a events

Tags: rpc, events, golang

I am using

github.com/centrifuge/go-substrate-rpc-client

And able to get list of events from each block and also able to filter it out but is there a way to identify which contract triggered the event.

Comment: Have you seen https://github.com/paritytech/subxt ? As I say you tagged rust I assumed rust based subscription is what you wanted. If historical, you likely want something else like an indexer or block explorer.

Comment: I am using Golang interface to catch events emitted by contracts in rust. As application is written in golang.

Answer (score 1):

The [ContractsEmitted](https://github.com/centrifuge/go-substrate-rpc-client/blob/015965cf2e670ceb9b87ae40a8ddfe7ee8114a8f/types/events.go#L2963) event layout has `Contract` field - this is what you need.